# What is the connection between Rosh Hashana and honey?

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, honey

Although I initially thought honey was just a nice Rosh Hashana siman for a "sweet new year", the [Likutei Maharich](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48754&st=&pgnum=24) quotes the Arizal who reveals that there is a deeper connection between the two: The posuk representing the Shem Hashem of Tishrei is ׳**ודבש** ׳היום ׳הזה ׳ה׳, based on the two pesukim [Devarim 26:15-16](https://www.sefaria.org/Tikkunei_Zohar.9b.10?vhe=Tikkunei_Zohar&lang=bi&p2=Deuteronomy.26.15&lang2=bi&aliyot2=0). (cf. [Bnei Yissachor Tishrei 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Bnei_Yissaschar%2C_Tishrei.1.1.1?vhe=Bnei_Yisaschar,_Piotrkow_1883&lang=bi&with=Navigation&lang2=en)).

What is the deeper connection between Rosh Hashana and honey that even the Shem Hashem of Tishrei is connected to honey?

Comment: I could make something up...milk=shavuous and honey=R"H each is a food which would otherwise be not kosher except that H' said it is kosher. These 2 holidays celebrate God and the acceptance of God's law.

Comment: I don't know about the sheim Hashem but there are other reasons why honey is more than just because it is sweet, and we want a sweet new year. Let me know if you would like other reasons.

Comment: @rosends there is actually a long piece about various liquids and their relation to individual yomim tovim - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12624/source-for-this-remez-expansion-of-%d7%99%d7%93-%d7%a9%d7%97%d7%98-%d7%93%d7%9d

Comment: Devash in the Bible means anything sweet, even if made from fruit. https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.2.12?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Leviticus.2.11.1&lang2=he&w2=Gur%20Aryeh&lang3=he